# Need help to identify this LEGO set - white, gold, grey, blue, and earth tones

Tags: set-identification

I need help identifying this LEGO set. I lost the box. I just have the pieces in their plastic package.

[image: Lego pieces]

Answer (score 12):

I looks like it is some of the parts of [Master Wu Dragon](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70734-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), set number 70734.
[image]

It's the only set which contains both [Pearl Gold Wedge 4 x 3 Open with Cutout and 4 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47755#T=C&C=115) and [Dark Orange Slope, Curved 4 x 1 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13547#T=C&C=68) according to Bricklink.
[image: Pearl Gold Wedge 4 x 3 Open with Cutout and 4 Studs]
[image: Dark Orange Slope, Curved 4 x 1 Inverted]

Comment: You can see [bag #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yVQ5.png) in this unboxing video; https://youtu.be/NjsXwlUhnJY?t=79

Comment: Bingo! thank u! You got it right , the set is the bag 3 of  70734,so can someone give me a link to the booklet to be able to build it

Comment: @Hiba You can find instructions for most sets on lego.com: https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search?q=70734